# Test Django validator with parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to test a custom validator for an `ImageField` that checks that the aspect ratio of the image is between the given parameters. The validator takes a `min_aspect_ratio` and a `max_aspect_ratio` parameter, and returns a `validator` function, which takes the image from the `ImageField`:

```
def validate_image_aspect_ratio(min_aspect_ratio: int, max_aspect_ratio: int):
    """Checks that the proportions of an image (width / height) are what we expect."""

    def validator(image):
       if image is None:
            return

        aspect_ratio = image.width / image.height
        error_message = _(
            'Image\'s height proportion to its width should be between %(min_aspect_ratio)s and %(max_aspect_ratio)s. '
        'It was %(aspect_ratio)s.'
        ) % {
            'aspect_ratio': "{:.2f}".format(aspect_ratio),
            'min_aspect_ratio': min_aspect_ratio,
            'max_aspect_ratio': max_aspect_ratio
        }

        if aspect_ratio < min_aspect_ratio or aspect_ratio > max_aspect_ratio:
            raise ValidationError(
                error_message
            )

    return validator
```

Here's how I am using the validator:

```
image = models.ImageField(
    _('Image'),
    help_text=_('A default image will be used if this is not set.'),
    blank=True,
    validators=[validate_image_aspect_ratio(1.25, 1.35)]
)
```

Now I want to test this method, for which I will give it two arguments for the aspect-ratio range, but how do I pass the image to it? The problem is not creating a mock image for the test, just how do I pass it to the function, since it is passed to the returned function by the field. Thanks.

Comment: `validate_image_aspect_ratio(1.25, 1.35).validate(myimage)`

Comment: For that, `validate_image_aspect_ratio` should actually be a class with a `validate` method, right? It doesn't work with a function.

Comment: @EllDuderino: sorry, misread, then it is `validate_image_aspect_ratio(1.25, 1.35)(myimage)`,